# PHP Why the imported csv file only insert the first row of csv to SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have 3 row in the .csv file with 3 column. In that case I need to import the exact same file for 3 times to get all my data in the .csv file to completely inserted into my SQL database. I thought `!feof($file)` should make sure the looping through the end of file?

```
if (isset($_POST['submitI'])){
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    while (!feof($file)){
        $getData = fgetcsv($file, '0');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM murid WHERE No_Sek_Murid = '".$getData[0]."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(empty($getData[0] || $getData[1] || $getData[2])){
            $errorForm = "Sila isikan semua medan dalam fail!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errorForm');</script>";
            echo "<script> location.href='../main.php'; </script>";
            exit();
        }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0){
            $sqlMurid = "INSERT INTO murid (No_Sek_Murid, Nama_Murid, Kelas_Murid) VALUES ('".$getData[0]."', '".$getData[1]."', '".$getData[2]."')";
            $sqlKelab = "INSERT INTO kelab (Kod_Kelab, No_Sek_Murid, ID_Pengguna) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['kodKelab']}', '".$getData[0]."', '{$_SESSION['username']}')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sqlMurid);
            mysqli_query($conn, $sqlKelab);

            $success = "Berjaya menambah rekod ke dalam pangkalan data!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$success');</script>";
            echo "<script> location.href='../main.php'; </script>";
            exit();
        }

    } fclose($file);

} else {
    $errorfile = "Operasi import gagal!";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errorfile');</script>";
    echo "<script> location.href='../main.php'; </script>";
    exit(); 
}
```

}

Comment: Remove exit(); from your 4th if statement..

Comment: also seems like we would want to do   priming read from the file, before the while loop, and another read at the very end of the loop, before we go back up to the conditional test (in the `while`).

Comment: You have SQLInjection vulnerabilities in your code.  You may think a CSV is safe because it's a file, but it's not.  If you allow end users to upload these files, it's no better then putting `$_REQUEST` concatenated right in your queries.  Never concatenate data into a query, its just not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use exit() unnecessarily. Also you passed multiple parameters to empty() function which seems incorrect. You can run your code without exit function as below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitI'])){
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    while (!feof($file)){
        $getData = fgetcsv($file, '0');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM murid WHERE No_Sek_Murid = '".$getData[0]."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(empty($getData[0]) || empty($getData[1]) || empty($getData[2])){
            $errorForm = "Sila isikan semua medan dalam fail!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errorForm');</script>";
            echo "<script> location.href='../main.php'; </script>";
        } elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0){
            $sqlMurid = "INSERT INTO murid (No_Sek_Murid, Nama_Murid, Kelas_Murid) VALUES ('".$getData[0]."', '".$getData[1]."', '".$getData[2]."')";
            $sqlKelab = "INSERT INTO kelab (Kod_Kelab, No_Sek_Murid, ID_Pengguna) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['kodKelab']}', '".$getData[0]."', '{$_SESSION['username']}')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sqlMurid);
            mysqli_query($conn, $sqlKelab);

            $success = "Berjaya menambah rekod ke dalam pangkalan data!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$success');</script>";
            echo "<script> location.href='../main.php'; </script>";
        }

    } fclose($file);

} else {
    $errorfile = "Operasi import gagal!";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errorfile');</script>";
    echo "<script> location.href='../main.php'; </script>";
}
```